# array size in new-expression must be constant (dynamic array)

Tags: c++, arrays

Hello everyone i'm trying to make a class which is basically a 3D matrix of ones and zeros. Unfortunately when i try to dynamically allocate the 3D matrix in the constructor, the console throws me :
"array size in new-expression must be constant" i don't why it happens, compilator seems to think that it's a static array.

here's the code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
class map
{
public:
map( int, int, int,std::string);
~map();
private:

int  dx,dy,dz;
std::string generatorName;
bool* matrix3D;
};
map::map(int  x=0,int  y=0,int  z=0,std::string gen="EMPTY")
{
    matrix3D=new bool[x][y][z];
    generatorName=gen;
}
map::~map()
{
     delete matrix3D;
}
```

Comment: C++ doesn't let you allocate multidimensional arrays of variable sizes. You'll need to either allocate a single, long, one-dimensional array and use your own indexing tricks to simulate a 3D array, or you'll need to break the allocation down into multiple smaller steps.

Comment: You cannot allocate multidimensional arrays like that, and you are missing a `[]` in  your call to `delete`, and you should use a 3D `vector` of `bool` instead of your `bool*`.

Comment: First, I wouldn't call my class `map`, as there already is a `std::map` class in C++.  Second, container classes such as `std::vector` takes care of this for you.  Third, your attempted `map` class will suffer from bugs as soon as you try to copy / assign with it due to the lack of the "rule of 3" being implemented.

Comment: Thanx for your answers, i didn't know there was a map class in std, why is there a such limitaton in c++ for 3D matrice? yeah i forgot ´[]´ my bad, i was focused on the array error ^^ Thanks anyway :)

Comment: There are no "dynamic arrays" in C++ unless you use the standard library or create your own.  Arrays in C++ are fixed in size, and the sizes are determined at compile time.  Also, `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<bool>>>` would have worked, but won't be the most efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the function templated and pass the size that way instead.

```
template <size_t N, etc>
...

Array [N]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your program to work as is, including using `[ ]` to access each dimension, you can do this using [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

```
#include <vector>
//...
typedef std::vector<bool> boolArray;
typedef std::vector<boolArray> boolArray2D;
typedef std::vector<boolArray2D> boolArray3D;

class mymap
{
    public:
        mymap( int, int, int,std::string);

    private:
        int  dx,dy,dz;
        std::string generatorName;
        boolArray3D matrix3D;
};

mymap::mymap(int  x=0,int  y=0,int  z=0,std::string gen="EMPTY") :
      matrix3D(x, boolArray2D(y, boolArray(z))), generatorName(gen) 
{}
```

You don't need to have a destructor, and your existing code that uses `[ ]` should work.

Note that this is not as efficient as using a one dimensional array and using indexing to get to a certain x / y / z component.  But that requires you to change some of your existing code (using one `[ ]` instead of `[ ][ ][ ]` to access your elements).

Answer (score -1):

So, i assume vector's purpose is to make array more easy to use but i find template's "grammar" excessively complicated and unintuitive... So instead, i tried to make a pointer to an array of pointers to other arrays of pointers.
Here's my final result, the only thing that bother me is the destructor, am i really releasing all the memory i've allocated?

```
#include <iostream>

class airMap
{
public:
    airMap( int, int, int,std::string);
    ~airMap();

private:

    int  dx,dy,dz;
    std::string generatorName;
    bool*** matrix3D;


};

//Constructeurs et destructeurs
airMap::airMap(int  x=0,int  y=0,int  z=0,std::string gen="EMPTY")
{
    matrix3D=new bool**[x];
    for (int i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        matrix3D[i]=new bool*[y];
        for (int j=0;j<y;j++)
        {
            matrix3D[i][j]=new bool[z];
        }
    }
    dx=x;
    dy=y;
    dz=z;
    generatorName=gen;
}
airMap::~airMap()
{

    for(int i=0;i<dx;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<dy;j++)   
        {
            delete[] matrix3D[i][j];
        }
        delete[] matrix3D[i];
    }
    delete[] matrix3D;
}
```

Comment: I can break your class with just two lines of code: `{airMap a1(1,1,1,"abc"); airMap a2 = a1;}`  I just created a double-free error.  If you need convincing, run that program and watch the sparks fly at the last curly brace.  Your implementation lacks a user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator.  If you want "untuitiveness", go write those two functions to fix the errors.  Or just use `std::vector`, and not worry about all of this.

Comment: *i find template's "grammar" excessively complicated and unintuitive* -- Well maybe C++ isn't your language, since templates are now a staple.  Also, many would disagree with you, and find it easy.

Comment: And here is the same code using vector.  http://ideone.com/ZyizlB  No errors.  Not only that, I even added functions to return some of the information, like the array and the name.

Comment: And here is the fix to your code:  http://ideone.com/ZtsmLj  So tell me, does this look intuitive to you without a full explanation of what was done?  The `vector` code doesn't look so bad now, does it?